# Comparing text: what is the best approach

Tags: javascript, php, compare, textmatching

I have a database which stores sequential versions of a text file. What I would like to do is allow the user to call up any two historical files (e.g version 1 And version 4) and compare them for differences:

1. Spelling changes
2. New words / new sentences / new paragraphs
3. Moved paragraphs
4. Etc

Basically an online GIT but for text files not code.

I figure JavaScript is probably the best approach and I presume that there must be an open source library but I simply cannot find one.

Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [Mergely](http://www.mergely.com/doc), it does a wonderful job

Comment: Thank you. I have looked at mergely but it doesn’t seem to do a great job at managing moved paragraphs - do I need to ha file that separately?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running under linux, you could install `diff`, save both files in temp files, then compare them using the `shell_exec` command.

For example

```
$tmp1 = 'myfile.txt';
$tmp2 = 'myfile2.txt';    
$output = shell_exec('diff -y {$tmp1} {$tmp2}');
```

Look at `man diff` for an option that suits your needs.